# IIS virtual directories created by Visual Studio 16.8.4

Tags: virtual, iis-express

When debugging in VS by IIS Express (Google Chrome), virtual directories are created. Sometimes I have an error like below:

Failed to register URL "http://localhost:60000/" for site "Floow.Admin.UI.Web(1)" application "/". Error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x80070020)

The step I take is changing the portnumber, so I can proceed.

But meanwhile I have a lot of these virtual directories. Can I delete the Virtual Directories somehow? I can't find them in IIS.

[EDIT]

This image is sometimes shown too and belongs to the issue.

[image]

[/EDIT]

Comment: "I can't find them in IIS" is expected, because IIS Express uses different configuration files, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-solution-file

Answer (score 1):

Error code 0x80070020 means ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION, which in the case of IIS Express means that the port that it is attempting to listen on is being used by another process.

Use the netstat command to find out which application is using the port and then solve the problem.

```
netstat -ao | findstr <port_number_to_search_for>
```

The `a` parameter tells netstat to display all connections and listening ports.

The `o` parameter tells netstat to display the process ID associated with the connection.

Comment: No result is given. I waited a while and started the debugging process. Got the message as in my edited question. Any idea?

Comment: 1.open the folder in which your solution is 2.remove the .vs folder (it may be hidden) 3.restart Visual Studio 4.hit F5 to start IIS Express and debug your application

Comment: When I get the issue again I will try your solution.

Comment: I tried to remove the .vs folder. But no solution. When starting IIS Express from VS, no dialog with the process id. But no website in Chrome tab with the debugged application. Could be some other issue and probably needs a next step.